# Drupal Commerce Mirgrate product displays

Tags: commerce, migrations

I'm trying to create a migration class for my product displays. I already have one for the product variations which is seperate because it has a different CSV source.

So I'm just trying to create the drupal nodes of the product displays. When I check the database in the node table, the nodes are there with the correct type. However when I go to the product page, I don't see the new items there.

I think it has something to do with this line:

```
$this->destination = new MigrateDestinationNode('video_storage_recorder');
```

or

```
$this->map = new MigrateSQLMap($this->machineName,
      array(
        'Name' => array(
          'type' => 'varchar',
          'length' => 255,
          'not null' => TRUE,
          'description' => 'Recorder',
        ),
      ),
      //MigrateDestinationCommerceProduct::getKeySchema('commerce_product')
      //MigrateDestinationEntityAPI::getKeySchema('video_storage_recorder')
      MigrateDestinationNode::getKeySchema('video_storage_recorder')
    );
```

where video_storage_recorder is my content type.

Also I tried

```
$this->destination = new MigrateDestinationEntityAPI('video_storage_recorder');
```

But no different behaviour.

I think the nodes are created but not considered products for Drupal Commerce. But I don't know why.
Also Migrate does not give any (error) messages and just says 9 items were created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I added a product variation in code the product appeared in the list. It's required to have at least one variation to be linked for the product display to be considerd a product display.